# Text left aligned not centred on android

Tags: react-native

Using https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html - I am trying to center text within my html, however, it is always left aligned, how can I center my text?

```
     <View style={common.bannerText}>
                <View style={common.textCenter}>
                     <HTML html="<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>" />
                </View>
           </View>
```

Styles:

```
  bannerText: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: colors.GREEN,
    fontFamily: fonts.REGULAR,
    fontSize: fonts.FONT_SIZE_MEDIUM,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginVertical: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  textCenter: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to doc , pass a prop "contentWidth" to set the width of that HTML container and use "containerStyle" to style that content to your needs.

Comment: A link to the doc could be usefull